# filter array based on another nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays

In the code below, I apply filter on array based on other arrays. For example : Filter `data` array based on property names from `cols` and values from `values` array.

```js
const
    data = [{ name: "Tiger Nixon", position: "Accountant", salary: 10800, start_date: "2011\\/04\\/25", office: "Edinburgh", rating: 5421 }, { name: "Garrett Winters", position: "Accountant", salary: 170750, start_date: "2011\\/07\\/25", office: "Tokyo", rating: 8422 }, { name: "Garrett Winters", position: "Analyst", salary: 170750, start_date: "2011\\/07\\/25", office: "Tokyo", rating: 8422 }, { name: "Ashton Cox", position: "Junior Technical Author", salary: 86000, start_date: "2009\\/01\\/12", office: "San Francisco", rating: 1562 }, { name: "Cedric Kelly", position: "Senior Javascript Developer", salary: 433060, start_date: "2012\\/03\\/29", office: "Edinburgh", rating: 6224 }],
    cols = ['name', 'position'],
    values = ['Garrett Winters', 'Accountant'],
    result = data.filter(o => cols.every((k, i) => o[k] === values[i]));
    
    console.log(result);
```

The above code is working fine. But if I have nested array for numeric in `values` (see below). I want to accommodate this condition `salary >= nestedarray[0] && salary <= nestedarray[1]`

```
cols = ['salary', 'position']
values = [[50000,500000], 'Accountant']
```

I tried this but not working -

```
result = data.filter(o => cols.every((k, i) => if(Array.isArray(values[i]) {o[k] >= values[i][0] && o[k] <= values[i][1] } else {o[k] === values[i]}))
```

Comment: So what's stopping you? Use an `if` statement that checks whether `values[i]` is an array. If it is, use that test.

Comment: @Barmar I am new to JS. I tried if statement but it's not working

Comment: Show what you tried and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. I just pasted in the post what I tried

Comment: `if` is not an expression, it needs to be in a function body surrounded by `{}`.

Comment: Or you could use a `?:` ternary expression.

Comment: You also have a typo. The second `>=` should be `<=`.

Comment: On top of missing `{}` to wrap the `if`, there is a missing closing-paranthesis at: `if(Array.isArray(values[i])`. It needs to be `if(Array.isArray(values[i]))`

Comment: I think that using forEach to construct a new array would be easier logic to understand for what you are trying to do, for example: https://pastebin.com/raw/bkAcuRnJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the ternary operator to perform a conditional in an expression, not `if`.

```
result = data.filter(o => cols.every((k, i) => 
    Array.isArray(values[i]) ? 
        o[k] >= values[i][0] && o[k] <= values[i][1] :
        o[k] === values[i]
    ));
```